# React AJAX takes minutes to load simple response on '/' but takes milliseconds on '/home'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, jwt

My react code gets the account information (email, name, pictures etc..) When I load / when logged in it takes minutes to load and bring back the json response, but when on /home it takes milliseconds.
Component that /home extends:

```
constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = this._getAccountState();
    }

    _getAccountState() {
        return {
            account: AccountStore.account
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(!this.state.account) {
            AccountService.getAccountInfo();
        }

        this.changeListener = this._onChange.bind(this);

        AuthStore.addChangeListener(this.changeListener);
        AccountStore.addChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    }

    _onChange() {
        this.setState(this._getAccountState());
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        AuthStore.removeChangeListener(this.changeListener);
        AccountStore.removeChangeListener(this.changeListener);
    }
```

Service that is triggered when a user logs in, or a user is authenticated and loads the app:

```
    getAccountInfo() {
    request({
        url: ACCOUNT_INFO_URL,
        method: 'get',
        crossOrigin: true,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AuthStore.jwt
        }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            AccountActions.getAccountInfo(response);
        });
    }
```

Account action that triggers the app dispatcher:

```
getAccountInfo: (account) => {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: GET_ACCOUNT_INFO,
        account: account
    })
}
```

AccountStore:

```
class AccountStore extends BaseStore {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.subscribe(() => this._registerToActions.bind(this));

    this._account = null;
}

_registerToActions(action) {
    switch(action.actionType) {
        case GET_ACCOUNT_INFO:
            this._account = action.account;

            this.emitChange();

            break;

        case LOGOUT_ACCOUNT:
            this._account = null;

            this.emitChange();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

get account() {
    return this._account;
}
}
```

I have NO idea why it functions the second I click out of the index page.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't an issue on server-side?

Comment: can you show us the reducer? It sounds like your not updating the state with a new immutable object so react doesn't know to re-render until you click.

Comment: @iofjuupasli Absolutely. I have tried it several hundred times, and rit when the server gets the request it sends a response back.

Comment: @BlairAnderson Updated with AccountStore. It should update though, because I added a change listener to the component, so when the account store updates, so does the component.

Comment: put a debugger inside your `_onChange()` function to see if data is ever being changed. if not then you have a problem with your store/ajax. if it is changing then you have a problem with how your component subscribes to changes